# Cisco Aironet 1040 and 1260 Migrate from Standalone/Autonomous Mode to Lightweight/Controller-Based Mode

Tags: cisco, migration, access-point, lightweight

Is there a way to migrate an a Cisco Aironet 1260 and also a Cisco Aironet 1040 both in Standalone/Autonomous Mode to Lightweight/Controller-Based Mode so they can be managed through a Cisco Wireless Controller (Model 2504) or can they be managed in the current mode they are with the WLC?

IMHO seems that a simple upgrade/flash to the firmware using the images on the Download Area, should be enough but i prefer to ask first before start experimenting with these ideas myself.

At least on the overview of the cisco aironet products, it suggest the Standalone versions are sell as a entry option to quickly start using Cisco AP's and then migrate all to Cisco centralized-management (WLC's), however some [old documentation (PDF)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/wireless/ps5678/ps6521/product_at_a_glance0900aecd805df476.pdf)
 doesn't list both particular APs as supported (at least for his all-in-one migration utility).

Last link i found searching was in [cisco forum asking the same question](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2065677) but the answers actually only encourage this from already lightweight AP to autonomous and revert the change, doesn't seem to talk from a purchased autonomous to lightweight...

So please if you have a link about the procedure or you know the procedure the migrate/convert this AP's or a way to control them directly in autonomous mode please answer this question...

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the upgrade tool is for older access points than the one you have.  On the newer access points you can just tftp a lightweight firmware image.  The difference is the newer access points have a "manufacturer installed certificate" or MIC burned into the flash.  The conversion tool creates the certificate on the older access points.  This is why the download for the conversion tool is listed only under the older access points.

[Cisco documentation, description under "LAP Authorization"](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6366/products_configuration_example09186a00808c7234.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a separate tool for converting standalone APs to lwapp if you don't have WCS or Prime.

Some models require the use of a lwapp recovery image and not the tool.

Comment: Can you be more specific?... since you suggest there is a tool but there is no tool in the downloads sections only the firmware.

Comment: If there is no tool in the download section for your AP, there will be a LWAPP recovery image.